# Error When Running Flutter Web in Debug and Release

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying to run Flutter Web, but I am getting the following error when running in release mode:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString')
    at Object.bm (main.dart.js:442)
    at Object.aD8 (main.dart.js:75)
    at main.dart.js:7583
    at aeF.a (main.dart.js:5177)
    at aeF.$2 (main.dart.js:32691)
    at Object.F (main.dart.js:5163)
    at Object.tA (main.dart.js:7601)
    at Object.aDT (main.dart.js:7578)
    at main.dart.js:20403
    at aeF.a (main.dart.js:5177)
```

and the following error when running in debug mode:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'append')
    at main.dart.js:65
```

The same thing happens when running the app in debug mode.

The app works when running on mobile.

Comment: Try using null safety

Comment: @MohitKushwaha I am using null safety

Comment: I ended up updating some stuff and it works now!

Comment: what did you update to solve the problem? @KetZoomer

Comment: I updated flutter, android studio and some other android studio extensions